# ¿Cómo me refiero al componente "Post-process Layer" desde el script en unity?

Tags: c#, unity

Quiero poder desactivar el componente "Post-process Layer" de la cámara en unity, pero al usar `gameobject.GetComponent<PostprocessLayer>().enabled = false;` me da todo tipo de errores con la parte entre "<>" en específico, solo necesito saber qué escribir entre los "<>" para que funcione, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con poner la segunda 'P' de PostProcessLayer debería funcionar correctamente

```
gameobject.GetComponent<PostProcessLayer>().enabled = false;
```

Si desde el inspector das click derecho en el componente Post-process Layer y seleccionas la opción Edit Script. Podrás ver el nombre exacto de la class.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente imagen se ve el nombre de la class del componente Post-process Layer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Aunque deberías ser más específico con los errores que te aparecen

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, y me da este error en específico: "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PostProcessLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Y el script está como componente en la cámara y usé exactamente la línea de código que me mencionaste (por no decir que la copié y la pegué tal como está).

Comment: Ve a Window -> package manage y reinstala el paquete de PostProcessing a ver si así se soluciona el error de referencias.